# Same SQL query give different results on the same MySQL server and DB

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running the following mysql query:

```
SELECT
    MAX(CONCAT('FY', weeks.fy, ' Q', weeks.q, 'W', weeks.wInQuarter)) AS `Fiscal Week`,
    SUM(cb_arr.total) AS `Cloud Backup Service Total`
FROM 
  billing.customers c 
JOIN 
  billing.date_fiscal_weeks weeks
LEFT JOIN 
  cloud_backup_service.arr_customers cb_arr 
ON cb_arr.src_id = c.alias AND weeks.weekDate = cb_arr.weekDate
WHERE 
  weeks.weekDate>'2020-04-19'
GROUP BY 
  weeks.weekDate
```

However each time I run it I get different output:

[image]

Any idea what is the issue here?

Thanks,
SHmulik.

Comment: Usually, we group by something in the select, in your case, I will change the group by for `GROUP BY 0` (the first field in the select).

Comment: @jmaitrehenry there is a group by being part of the query: `GROUP BY 
  weeks.weekDate`. The numbers in the screenshot don't add up to the same overall sum which should be the case when I look at your query. Is the database you query part of a cluster or replica?

Comment: @SaschaM78 The `GROUP BY` in the query is not using a field used in the `SELECT`. Without `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode, the query could send inconsistent result as MySQL will choose any value from the group and could have inconsistent result: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: @jmaitrehenry good point and thanks for adding a reference.

Comment: @SaschaM78 no there is no replica and its not cluster. one mysql version 8.0.12 running in docker.

Comment: Amazing issue fixed by upgrading MySQL to version 8.0.20.

Comment: It is fixed by the upgrade, because in MySQL 8.0 `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode is the default (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html)